# Keras multi-class classification loss is too high

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

I am training a model in multi class classification to generate texts. Below is a sample of the dataset.

| state | district | month | rainfall | max_temp | min_temp | max_rh | min_rh | wind_speed | advice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orissa | Kendrapada | february | 0.0 | 34.6 | 19.4 | 88.2 | 29.6 | 12.0 | chances of foot rot disease in paddy crop; apply urea at 3 weeks after transplanting at active tillering stage for paddy;...... |
| Jharkhand | Saraikela Kharsawan | february | 0 | 35.2 | 16.6 | 29.4 | 11.2 | 3.6 | provide straw mulch and go for intercultural operations to avoid moisture losses from soil; chance of leaf blight disease in potato crop; ....... |

Below is my code through which the model is made.

```py
def create_model():
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='state')
    input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='district')
    input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='month')
    input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='rainfall')
    input5 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_temp')
    input6 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_temp')
    input7 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_rh')
    input8 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_rh')
    input9 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='wind_speed')
    xz= [input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8, input9]
    x1= layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input1)
    x2=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input2)
    x3=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input3)
    x4=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input4)
    x5=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input5)
    x6=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input6)
    x7=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input7)
    x8=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input8)
    x9=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input9)
    base_model =  layers.Add()([x1,x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9])
    first_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_1')(base_model) 
    second_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_2')(base_model)
    third_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_3')(base_model)
    fourth_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_4')(base_model)
    fifth_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_5')(base_model)
    models = tf.keras.Model(inputs=xz,
                  outputs=[first_output, second_output, third_output, fourth_output, fifth_output])
    return models
```

The code for my model compilation.

```py
model=create_model()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'output_1': 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'output_2': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_3': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_4': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_5': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'output_1':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_2':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_3':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_4':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_5':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()})
```

Finally, the problem I am facing, the loss and accuracy. Loss is too high.

```
Epoch 499/500
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 66362.0130 - output_1_loss: 5827.9458 - output_2_loss: 10478.4935 - output_3_loss: 16566.5957 - output_4_loss: 16831.8887 - output_5_loss: 16657.0967 - output_1_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_2_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_3_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_4_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_5_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 500/500
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 66362.0130 - output_1_loss: 5827.9458 - output_2_loss: 10478.4935 - output_3_loss: 16566.5957 - output_4_loss: 16831.8887 - output_5_loss: 16657.0967 - output_1_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_2_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_3_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_4_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - output_5_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Kindly help me and correct me where I am wrong. I am total newbie to this field.

**Alternative Model Update**

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(150),
])
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It have the [5,30] shaped input reshaped to  [150].

Comment: What classes are you trying to predict? Only possible classes I see are `state`, `district` and `month`.

Comment: have you tried to reduce the learning rate? maybe it is case of exploding gradient

Comment: The classes I am trying to predict are the ```advices``` which are in shape of [5,30]. Actually further in my code I had separated the [5,30] single column into 5 colums each with a tensor of shape [30].

Comment: Are they one-hot encoded?

Comment: @yudhiesh Well, no they are not one hot encoded. I used the Keras text preprocessing's Tokenizer and pad_sequences.

Comment: Your code would be a lot more readable if you just passed 9 inputs into your model and had one dense layer of size 128, and then passed this into a sum. It would perform the exact same operation but be a bit less confusing.

Comment: @yudhiesh Here is how they are encoded.  ``` array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 54, 55, 21, 56, 57,  3, 22, 19, 58,  6, 59,  4, 60,  1, 61, 62, 23, 63, 23, 64], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 65,  7, 66,  2, 67, 68,  3, 69, 70].....] dtype=int32)```

Comment: @jhso Well, i get a little what you ar trying to say. I am posting an update to this qus at bottom, please see if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: @santhosh sure. for more intuitive explanation, check this https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/#:~:text=Exploding%20gradients%20are%20a%20problem,learn%20from%20your%20training%20data.  for a bit math introduction, go to here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhXZsFVxGKo.

Comment: Please do **not** post code or data in the comments - edit & update your question instead.

Comment: Check that data range in input is between 0-1, and if not (I do not see that in the code parts shown), make the preprocessing correspondingly. This may help partially your problem.

Comment: @Experience_In_AI I did normalized the inputs. Well that got my loss lower. But my accuracy is still varying between 0.1- 0.3

Comment: @SantoshKumar next try to change your "Add" principle to form of "Concatenate" to optimize proper infromation flow inside the network. I'll add the this idea as an separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the model structure please see the following example code, including a "model_simple" alternative for the original network. Train the both with the same input data, vary the structure of the "model_simple" and find out what structure results in the best accuracy.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def create_model():
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='state')
    input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='district')
    input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='month')
    input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='rainfall')
    input5 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_temp')
    input6 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_temp')
    input7 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_rh')
    input8 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_rh')
    input9 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='wind_speed')
    xz= [input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,input9]
    x1= layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input1)
    x2=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input2)
    x3=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input3)
    x4=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input4)
    x5=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input5)
    x6=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input6)
    x7=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input7)
    x8=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input8)
    x9=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input9)
    base_model =  layers.Add()([x1,x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9])
    first_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_1')(base_model)
    second_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_2')(base_model)
    third_output= layers.Dense(30,name='output_3')(base_model)
    fourth_output= layers.Dense(30,name='output_4')(base_model)
    fifth_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_5')(base_model)
    models = tf.keras.Model(inputs=xz,
                  outputs=[first_output,second_output,third_output,fourth_output,fifth_output])
    return models

def create_model_simple():
    input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='state')
    input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='district')
    input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='month')
    input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='rainfall')
    input5 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_temp')
    input6 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_temp')
    input7 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='max_rh')
    input8 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='min_rh')
    input9 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='wind_speed')
    #xz= [input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,input9]
    #x1=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input1)
    #x2=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input2)
    #x3=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input3)
    #x4=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input4)
    #x5=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input5)
    #x6=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input6)
    #x7=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input7)
    #x8=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input8)
    #x9=layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input9)
    yhdistelma=layers.concatenate([input1,input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7, input8, input9])
    #base_model =  layers.Add()([x1,x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9])
    first_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_1')(yhdistelma)
    second_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_2')(yhdistelma)
    third_output= layers.Dense(30,name='output_3')(yhdistelma)
    fourth_output= layers.Dense(30,name='output_4')(yhdistelma)
    fifth_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_5')(yhdistelma)
    models = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2,input3,input4,input5, input6, input7, input8, input9],
                  outputs=[first_output,second_output,third_output,fourth_output,fifth_output])
    return models

model=create_model()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'output_1': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_2': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_3': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_4': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_5': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'output_1':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_2':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_3':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_4':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_5':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()})

model.summary()

keras.utils.plot_model(model,'model_structure.png',show_dtype=True)


#Let's create a more simple model version:
model_simple=create_model_simple()

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'output_1': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_2': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_3': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_4': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_5': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'output_1':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_2':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_3':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_4':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_5':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()})

model_simple.summary()

keras.utils.plot_model(model_simple,'model_simple_structure.png',show_dtype=True)
```

...especially, please note that the key difference between your original and more simple model is that "Add" has been replaced with "Concatenate". The "Add" results in output size of same than one of its inputs, but the size of "Concatenate" output is much much higher, that kind of things may have an effect for the performance.

[image]

Comment: That made the code much simpler to understand.
Can I add LSTM to each output instead of a single Dense?